# Remove directive name from html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have implemented a code to remove the directive name from html code. Following is my directive

```
.directive('removeFixedHeader',[
    '$compile',
    function($compile){

        return{

            scope: {
                idToRemove: "@removeFixedHeader"
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.on('click', function () {
                    var elem = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.idToRemove));
                    var newHtml ='<div class="partialInner col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" id="callCenterFixedHeader">' + '<ng-include src="\'innerMain.html\'"/>'+ '</div>';

                    $compile(newHtml)(scope, function (el) {
                        elem.replaceWith(el);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The issue im having here is the content of innerMain.html not showing properly

Appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Please define "not showing properly"

Comment: I have added few ng-include tags in the  innerMain.html page. The contents of those pages are not visible after removing the directive